# Restkit dynamic mapping based on previous value

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm dealing with the following json:

```
{
"status":
    {
    "errorCode":{errCode},
    "errorMsg":{errMsg},
    },
"data":
    {
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2",
    "key3":"value3", 
    }
}
```

I need to use different mapping for the object in `data`, according to `errCode` value. I tried to use RKDynamicMapping, but got confused with the keyPaths..

Is there any way to achieve that?

**Edit:**

I'm using this code:

```
RKObjectMapping *infoMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Info class]];
[infoMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"data.key1":@"key1", @"data.key2":@"key2", @"data.key3:@"key3}];

RKDynamicMapping *dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];
[dynamicMapping addMatcher:[RKObjectMappingMatcher matcherWithKeyPath:@"status.errorCode" expectedValue:0 objectMapping:infoMapping]];

[dynamicActivateTravelMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:^RKObjectMapping *(id representation) {
    NSNumber *errorCode = [[representation valueForKey:@"status"] valueForKey:@"errorCode"];
    if ([errorCode integerValue] == WSErrorUnknown) {
        return unknownMapping;
    }
    else{
        return infoMapping;
    }
}];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:dynamicMapping method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:kResource keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

Well, basically this code works, but I have couple of issues with it:

1. It seems very ugly to keep writing "data.x" for each attribute of the mapping.
2. The result dictionary comes back with `NSNull` as the key for the "data" mapping. (its value is fine though..)

   ```
   status = "<ServerStatusCode: 0x155b2fa0>";
   "<null>" = "Info: 0x15535800>";
   ```

Comment: Show the dynamic mapping you tried and then we'll correct it. The dynamic mapping can use a key path to navigate to the correct item to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically when you create the dynamic mapping it should be:

```
[dynamicMapping addMatcher:[RKObjectMappingMatcher matcherWithKeyPath:@"status.errorCode" expectedValue:@0 objectMapping:infoMapping]];
```

Note the `@0`, because you should be passing an object (`NSNumber`), not a plain number (where 0 will equate to nil and another number will cause problems).

The other 2 complaints you have are just the way things are. The first is because you need to index into the data. Both are caused by the `keyPath:nil`, specifying that the data is accessed from the top level and that there is no key with which to access the result.

Comment: it all seems very wrong here, notice how I return the right mapping in the setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock method..(?!) Plus, the 'status' key does come back in the result (because of another mapping), isn't there a way to cause the data key to come back as well?

Comment: Status will be returned if that is the key path, but if you do that you don't have access to the data section (and vica-versa).

Comment: So there's nothing Restkit can do to solve this elegantly? and not getting NSNull as the key for the data..

Comment: By your definition of elegantly and for your situation, no, I don't believe so. Because there is no nesting of the data.